# Using pgrep on exec to get the PID

Tags: java, php, linux

I'm having some trouble when using `exec("pgrep java",$output);`.

On the terminal I execute the `pgrep java` and it returns the Process ID, but when I use the same command on PHP it doesn't outputs anything, I was thinking about permissions but I checked that PHP current user it's root.

I also tried `ps ax | grep java` and the outputs is this:

[image]

But when I use the terminal the output it's different:

[image]

The same happens when using ps aux | awk '/java/ {print $2}'

On PHP: `Array ( [0] => 14970 [1] => 14972 )`
On Terminal: `14084 & 14963`

I also would like to point out that everytime I refresh the page the PIDs that are get are new, meaning that they're not constant, this also happens with one PID on the terminal, but the 14084 is the one that it's constant.

What's the best way to use pgrep? Or is there another way to get the process ID?